# ¿Compartir el mismo espacio gráfico de un nodo con otro en un árbol en java?

Tags: java

[image: Árbol compartiendo nodos gráficamente]

Tengo el método para graficar el árbol, lo que sucede es que se grafica un nodo encima de otro, que método podría utilizar para que compartan el mismo espacio gráfico dos nodos?

Comment: Pon el código que tienes hasta ahora para que te puedan guiar mejor.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque preguntas solicitando ayuda con tareas escolares deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que realizó hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción del inconveniente específico que está teniendo para resolverlo. Por favor lee [ask]